# Redirect Loop in OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, redirect

I'm trying to direct the user to a certain page on my site (VB, MVC4) when a given condition is false, but I keep getting a redirect loop:

`Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.`

Here's my code:

```
Public Class UserValidation
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)

        If Not DoSomeInternalCheck() Then
            filterContext.Result =
                New RedirectToRouteResult(
                    New RouteValueDictionary() From {
                        {"controller", "Home"},
                        {"action", "MessagePage"}
                    }
                )
        End If

        MyBase.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)

    End Sub

End Class
```

What am I missing in order to keep the user off the rest of the site and only have them see this one page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change this filter so that is *doesn't* redirect users if they are accessing the home page you want to redirect them to!

The redirect result sends their browser a message that says "Go to this other URL instead." When they go to that other URL, their request passes through the same filter, which tells them "Go to this URL [the same one as before] instead." Eventually the browser gives up and figures (correctly) that you've probably hit some kind of infinite redirect loop.

Comment: I figured that was the issue, but I'm not sure how to make that check. I've tried unsuccessfully to examine filterContext to see if this is the "Home/MessagePage" request, but so far no luck. I'm sure I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: @gfrizzle: Try setting a breakpoint at the beginning of your `OnActionExecuting` and using a watch on `filterContext` to see what information is available to you, and what that information looks like on the Home/MessagePage request. From that, it should be fairly simple to come up with a criterion that will ignore that particular page.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    try
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        user = (LoginViewModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["user"];
        if (user == null)
        {
           
            if (filterContext.Controller is AccountController == false)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "Account", 
                    action = "Login"        
                }));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller = "Account",
            action = "Login"
        }));
    }
}
```